# jQuery Autocomplete KEYUP vs KEYPRESS vs KEYDOWN

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I have a large dataset about 300,000 records, and on top of that there is very little I can add to the query to whittle it down OTHER than what is typed in the search box.

The difference in keyup vs keydown isn't noticeable on an array of 10 fruits or a few hundred countries, but its HUGE when dealing with 300,000+ records and you need that first keystroke to knock off some choices.

To illustrate

```
// on FIRST keydown field value is blank as expected, 
// (value is present on keyup)

$('#autoCompleteField').keypress(function(){
  var formVal=$('#autoCompleteField').val();
});

// assume ive made it safely to my php form
// $formVal = jquery value shown above
// translates to query below

select('id','name') from myTable where name like '%%'
```

It would be fine to pull in a list of 10 fruits or a couple hundred countries, as it does on their demos without consequence, but for the unsuspecting person with 300,000+ records, it seems like a pretty big oversight.

Is there any reason why you SHOULDN'T use keyup?

Comment: If you're doing an autocomplete on 300K records  you're doing it wrong. Won't someone think of the electrons?!?!?!?!

Comment: If one wants to have a feature that can handle it, what would you use?

Comment: A.) You're asking for opinions, not rock solid answers. *"Am i wrong?"* B.) You have got to take your users into account. Please give us the use case where 300K choices are needed.

Comment: The query with NO criteria has 300,000.  The FIRST keydown sends a query that does not add any criteria since its a blank untouched field at that point, effectively asking for everything.  My question is... I have solved it by using keyup instead of keypress/keydown and I want to know why the plugins themselves just dont have that as a default.  Is there something wrong with that approach?

Answer (score 0):

I have built my own autocomplete task that works for 300,000+ records at warp speed.  The key was to only return a limited number of records with each keypress, in my case I used 10.  Heres my eloquent query.

$first3 & $last3 are my own variables, insert your own logic.

```
     $queries=largeData::select('FirstName','LastName')
     ->where('FirstName','like','%'.$first3.'%')
     ->where('LastName','like','%'.$last3.'%')
     ->take(10)
     ->get();
```

This did NOT work with the jquery plugins I tried.  It would deliver the first 10 alphabetical records, regardless of my search term, and on the second keystroke it would only use those 10 chosen as its search pool resulting in no records.

For the jQuery

```
$('#myAutoSearchBox').keyup(function(){

  var formVal=$('#myAutoSearchBox').val();
  var formVal=formVal.trim();
  var theURL='/getMyRecord'+formVal;

  if(formVal){
     ajaxGet_myAutoComplete(theURL);
     $('.rosterResults').show();
  }else{
     $('.rosterResults').hide();
  }

});
```

And finally, the ajax success function pushes my html to my rosterResults div.

```
function ajaxGet_myAutoComplete(theURL){
   $.ajax({
     url: theURL,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "html",

     success: function(response){
        $(".rosterResults").html(response);
     }
  });
}
```

This may seem super simple to anyone who knows a shred of jquery and ajax, but for those that do not, this was a solution I didnt find anywhere else that helped me.